# CoreData without inverse relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a data model where I have no inverse relation ship and I wonder if there is a way to fix this since XCode is complaining and Apple says entities should have an inverse.

I'm getting some player statistic data via a json api. To simplify it, a `Player` has some statistics for 3 and only 3 game modes alias  `Kits`. Each `Kit` has the **same** attribues such as `name`, `score` or `time`.

The json looks like this

```
{
  "player": {
    "uid": "123456",
    "name": "FooBar",
    "kits": {
      "support": {
        "id": 32,
        "score": 0,
        "stars": 0,
        "name": "Support",
        "time": 0,
        "spm": 0
      },
      "assault": {
        "id": 1,
        "score": 27624,
        "stars": 0,
        "name": "Assault",
        "time": 5329,
        "spm": 311.022706
      },
      "engineer": {
        "id": 2,
        "score": 44639,
        "stars": 0,
        "name": "Engineer",
        "time": 5758,
        "spm": 465.151094
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my model like this

[image: model]

With this, I can access the `Kits` in code using

```
Player *player = ....
Kit *supportKit = player.kits.support;
...
// do whatever I want with the support kit
```

The question is, is my model wrong? How can I model the core data where a relation "one to many" but limited to a given number and where the ordered matters.

cheers,
Jan

Comment: You need to have a relationship from Kits to player (and from Kit to Kits). They give all sorts of reasons in the documentation. However I know that sometimes it is inconvenient. In those cases I put a 'z' in front of the name (like "zplayer") so that it is out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

I only see 2 tables in your data - the player and the "kit" which comprises of 3 types  id=1 = assault, id=2 = engineer and id = 32 is support.

You will need to establish inverse relationship between the 2 tables so person_to_kit is 1 to many while kit_to_person is 1 to 1.  .... The relationship is virtual not based on any particular field although your individual tables will require keys to be designated.

Comment: Person_to_kit and Kit_to_person are relationships that you have to manually specify in core data. Although Core_data can use SQLLite as underlying db it is not really relational in the sense that SQLdatabases are,  so there is no need for a foreign key - although the table as defined in SQLLite will probably have a system generated one.

Comment: You should edit your own answer instead of adding comments to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always have an inverse relationship in Core Data. Even if you do not use that relationship -- Core Data will.

Second, core data is not a database.  It is an object map that *can* persist to a database.  Therefore, you do not need foreign keys or ids or anything else to represent the relationship.  The relationship details are handled by Core Data.

If this is not an existing application that needs to be migrated then just add a reverse relationship in the model and set it as the inverse.  You don't need to use it, you don't need to set it or touch it in any way.  Put it there just for Core Data.